# Is there a way I can write a series in WordPress?

Tags: posts, cms, books

What I mean by series is like writing a book. A reader should be able to click on the book and then proceed to read the chapters. I can probably mimic it by creating a page and then linking it to a series of posts. I am looking for a more natural way to present and navigate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used this plugin for a client site I did a while back...it might do what you need...[Organize Series plugin](http://unfoldingneurons.com/neurotic-plugins/organize-series-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: I have installed and configured the plugin. Organizing works well. I see references to a table of contents but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

Justin Tadlock's [Series](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/series/) plugin is great, and it uses a lot less resources than the Organize Series plugin. It's simple, and based off of WP's custom taxonomies, and is built by a reputable WP programmer.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin lacks documentation on the WordPress.org site. I would have to try on a dummy site to figure out.

Comment: The documentation is all in the readme. Justin is very good about that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify.  Organize Series uses WP's custom taxonomies as well.  Also, I now have it hosted at [organizeseries.com](http://organizeseries.com).  Not knocking Justin's plugin though - he's doing a lot of great stuff for WordPress :)

I hope orgseries works well for you James.

Comment: Thanks Darren. It works perfectly for my needs. Nice new web site.